# Bit-Strings In C

Tags: c, bitstring

I have to implement Bit-Strings in my Code (as per the parameters given in some Standard).

Some of the standard parameters are Bit-Strings (with different Lengths=3, 7, 24, 1024 etc).

I have defined them as: (Example: Bit-String of Length 3)

```
#define SIZE 1 

struct bt_string
{       
    /* Array will be min 1 Byte Long, 
     * this parameter stores the number of Bits 
     * actually being used */
    unsigned short int bit_length;

    char bit_string [SIZE];
} sample_bit_string;
```

I am not allowed to use bit-fields.

Can someone please suggest (if possible) any better way to implement this?

Comment: What are the exact requirements? What specific parts of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: The above implementation works for me. I was just looking for a better approach (if possible) - since the C Standard don't prove any way to decalre a one-bit long variable.

Comment: There are likely several ways to implement a bitstring class, but it is impossible to compare them without some way of measure which is "better."

Comment: Thanks. There are more ways in C++ but I can't find out any more ways in C except using bit-fields. Here, to get a 3-bit long variable, I have to spend around 4 bytes of memory

Comment: Several variations of what you have come to mind: use short, int, or long rather than char; use unsigned data type rather than signed; use a std::vector or a custom linked list instead of an array. Each of these have their tradeoffs. Deciding which is best isn't necessarily clear cut.

Comment: How are these bit "strings" going to be used?  Are you using them for serialization?  Do you care (much) about memory usage?  BTW, the 3 bit and 7 bit examples you gave seem odd (no pun intended)

Comment: @Code-Guru, OP _must_ use `unsigned`, else undefined behaviour lurks all over the place. For specific operations, http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html might be of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that the bitmap is what you are looking for.(wiki:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) And, a sample implementation ported from Linux kernel:http://code.google.com/p/ulib/source/browse/trunk/src/base/bitmap.c.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The above implementation is close to bitmap only. If I need a bitstring 7 bits long, I am taking a 1 byte long array & maintaining the bit-count for setting the 7 bits only. Bitmap also needs the same input.